# Data via prop not being displayed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have managed to get myself slightly confused.  I have an app where I can display all user profiles, this component is called all-profiles.  An example of this page is

```
<tr v-for="profile in profiles.data" :key="profile.id">
    <td>{{ profile.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ profile.user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ profile.created_at }}</td>
    <td>
        <router-link :to="{ name: user-profile, params: {
             id: profile.id }}" tag="a" exact> View Profile
        </router-link>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So nothing fancy here, just a simple loop.  When you click on the `router-link` for a specific profile, it takes you to that page, a component called user-profile.  I pass the profile id as a parameter.

So in the user-profile component, I display information about that profile. Most of the work is done in the created function

```
created() {
    let vm = this;

    let url = `/api/profile/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            this.profile = response.data;
            this.fileName = response.data.file_path;
            return d3.json(response.data.file_path);
        }).then(data => {
            //display some data
        }).catch(err => {
            //log error
        });
}
```

So I firstly make an axios call to pull information about that profile.  Each profile has a file_path which contains some processed data, in JSON form.  I load this using d3 and display the data.  This also works fine, no issues here.  The issue is on this page however, within the template tags, I load another component which needs the file_path in order to display some data
within the file in the form of a chart.  So I have

```
<barchart :file-name = this.fileName></barchart>
```

Now if I output fileName within the user-profile page, I can see it is correct.  Now in the barchart component, I have the prop

```
props: {
    fileName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}
```

And then in the created function, I have

```
created() {
    console.log(this.fileName);
}
```

So that should output the fileName I am passing via the prop, but it currently outputs nothing. I used to have this working, but I was using route parameters, and wanted to switch things to props instead.

I have a feeling that maybe the barchart component is loaded before the fileName is properly set?

I am not sure, is there anything obvious that might cause nothing to get outputted?

Thanks

Comment: At creation time the axios call will not be complete, so the initial value of the prop is going to be undefined or null. It will update later.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case.  Thanks

Comment: @katiehudson did you ever figure this out one I have a similar issue!

Answer (score 2):

Is it just as simple as: you are using ":filename = this.filename" in the template? The 'this' seems to be out of place?

Comment: Good catch. Should be `<barchart :file-name="fileName">`

Comment: That's actually unrelated, although it should be like that.  The issue is the loading.  If I pass the filename as a hardcoded path in data, it works.  It also works if I use v-if the not display the component until everything is loaded.